# adding origin name of volume group

Tags: lvm

I am not able to create a snapshot using LVM

```
[root@localhost 4GLV]# vgs
  VG            #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
  TCPDumpVolGRP   2   2   0 wz--n- 1.36T 1.47G
[root@localhost 4GLV]# lvcreate --name=mysql_snap --snapshot --size=150G /dev/mapper/TCPDumpVolGRP-4GLV/tokudb
  "/dev/mapper/TCPDumpVolGRP-4GLV/tokudb": Invalid path for Logical Volume
  The origin name should include the volume group.
  Run `lvcreate --help' for more information.
```

I am following the instructions mentioned on these pages:

```
http://www.packtpub.com/article/setting-up-mysql-replication-for-high-availability

http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_lvm_p2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you only have 1.47G free, yet you're passing `--size=150G`.  The `--size` parameter is how much space will be used to buffer incoming writes while the snapshot is active, and you need to have that much space free when you start.

From the output of vgs, it looks like your volume group is `TCPDumpVolGRP`, and I'm guessing your logical volume name is `tokudb`.  So your command line should actually be

```
# lvcreate --name=mysql_snap --snapshot --size=150G /dev/TCPDumpVolGRP/tokudb
```

(where `--size` is also made appropriate)